# Creating sprites at a specific coordinate?

Tags: objective-c, ipod-touch

Hey guys, How would I go about telling the computer to create a object/sprite at a specific coordinate (on the iPod touch screen)? Then I would want to tell the computer to create the sprite with a static Y coordinate and a dynamic X coordinate. Basically I'm trying to create the game avalanche. 
Thanks in advance guys!

-Dustin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an imageView and position it.

```
[mySprite setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to create multiple random sprites (of the same sprite)?

Comment: You mean various sprites in random locations? You might run a for loop, in that for loop is where you would have your sprite creation code, then in place of GCRectMake(x, y...) you'd create random x,y (search for how to do random numbers, lots of good stuff).

Comment: @Dustin Tran, have you looked into using the [Cocos2D framework?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)  It is a 2D Sprite engine for iOS and other platforms.

Comment: @icnivad, In the game avalanche, sprites (of the same sprite) starts at the top. They randomly spawn and fall down. So you're saying... 
for(int i = 1; i < maxSprites; i++). I am sort of confused as to how I would go about creating duplicate sprites. Since in my .h I created a UIImageView called object.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani, Yes, yesterday I installed the Cocos2D template. I just don't know how to use it yet. I downloaded the open-source tweejump off a website and tried to analyze the code and incorporate the ideas into my project.